# What are CrashpadMetrics.pma~xxx.TMP in AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data

Tags: google-chrome

I have hundred of file like `CrashpadMetrics.pma~xxx.TMP`, some created from a year ago in the folder `AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`

There is also a main `CrashpadMetrics-active.pma`.

What are thoses files and why aren't they delete every now and then ?

Can I safetly delete all the old `CrashpadMetrics.pma~xxx.TMP` as there are taking  lot of space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PMA files are for data collection- `CrashpadMetrics-active.pma` should not be removed manually.
[This thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/crashpad-dev/2YZHzOpeAT8) provides most of the answers, e.g.

> They are created if one activates "**Automatically send
>   usage statistics and crash reports to Google**" in Settings.

And another:

> The "live" (i.e. BrowserMetrics-identifier.pma) file has the data
>   shown in chrome://histograms.

There is also a link to the [source](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/crashpad/crashpad/util/misc/metrics.cc?q=misc/metrics.&sq=package:chromium&g=0&l=1) where the metrics are generated in the following functions:

```
    ExceptionEncountered
    CrashReportPending
    CrashReportSize
    CrashUploadAttempted
    CrashUploadSkipped
    ExceptionCaptureResult
    ExceptionCode
    ExceptionEncountered
    HandlerLifetimeMilestone
    HandlerCrashed
```

Note the stony silence on the questions regarding the existence of a PMA file *viewer*.
Think the tmp files are removed when Chrome is shutdown down gracefully, but if it aborts, they are ignored in future runs. According to [WinApp2](https://github.com/MoscaDotTo/Winapp2/issues/328), they can be removed manually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Apparently, they are also created when the setting "Automatically send usage statistics and crash reports to Google" is set to disable...